# MariaDB System Versioned Tables Do Not Work Locally Even After MariaDB upgrade

Tags: mariadb, amazon-rds

So I used to have mysql installed on my mac via homebrew. I stared by uninstalling it and then installed maria with `brew install mariadb`

This shows me this version

```
> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB, for osx10.17 (arm64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

and this:

```
mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB, for osx10.17 (arm64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I can run mariadb and connect to it fine with this command:

```
mariadb -u root -p
```

However, I am not able to use the new feature of mariaDB called system versioned tables.

I have followed this guide: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/ and entered this command

```
MySQL [(none)]> CREATE TABLE t (    x INT ) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

Which gives this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SYSTEM VERSIONING' at line 1
```

To test this further, I created a MariaDB instance in aws and connected to it locally with the same command which works fine. The version that RDS supports is `10.6`

***Question: "Why can't does my local instance of mariadb not recognize the keyword `SYSTEM`?***

I am not sure how to debug this locally and I would like to know why this version of mariadb is unable to recognize these command locally. Looking for some debugging tips.

EDIT: Another thing to check was to select version while in the mariadb console

```
MySQL [(none)]> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.28    |
+-----------+
```

Comment: What is the output of `select version();` on your local system?

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag because system versioning is only a feature of MariaDB, not current releases of MySQL. MariaDB started in 2010 as a fork of MySQL, but they have diverged enough that we should now think of them as different products, with some code in common.

Comment: select version(); shows: 8.0.28

Comment: Why would that show a different version than `mariadb --version`?

Comment: Looks like you dont actually have the version onstalled you think you have

Comment: I am sure you are right but I just installed it with homebrew the way that the mariadb guide says: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.0.28 is a MySQL version, which doesn't have [System Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/), only MariaDB does (at the time of this posting anyway).

As noted, `mysql --version` only shows the version of the MySQL (or MariaDB via compatibility links) client. It doesn't show the server version.

Comment: It seems like at this time, `brew install mariadb` does not install the latest version. Are there other ways to install a more recent version?

Comment: I ended up having to use docker to host it locally.